# Cannot resolve com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing android app backend with amazon cognito and lambda.

My Code:

```
package digits.digitsapp;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaFunction;

public interface MyInterface {

    @LambdaFunction
    String digitsLogin(PhoneInfo phoneInfo);

    @LambdaFunction(functionName = "digitsLogin")
    void noDigitsLogin(PhoneInfo phoneInfo);
}
```

app(build.gradle) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.testing"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'

compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+'
}
```

My problem is Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+
when i add lambda sdk then i sync gradle then error comes.

please tell me what to do

Comment: What's your repository setting? Would you please post the full build.gradle file? The lambda library should be available on Maven and jCenter.

Comment: @Yangfan please check full build.gradle file.

Comment: what's the error when you sync gradle?

Comment: Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+

Comment: Would you please build the app via command line and turn on debugging? Run "gradlew assemble --debug".

Comment: @Yangfan thank you so much for your support, my problem is solved, it seems problem with android studio, it was automatically solved. if any issues comes in future i will ping you.